# jquery mobile: list view, on split button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have list view, each list item has split button 'delete'. How to determine which item was clicked ?

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/gDea8/83/

```
$("#listview a.ui-li-link-alt").live("click", function(e){
  alert('which item ? 1,2,3 or 4 ?'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#listview a.ui-li-link-alt").live("click", function(e){
      alert($(this).parent().index() +1); 
});
```

<sub>(Any chance to update your jQuery version and use the `.on()` method?)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for answer...Concerning '.on', i'm not really familiar wit that ) But I will look. Thanks.